# In reference to the patent: [US3792680][1]

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US3792680](https://www.google.com/patents/US3792680)

Is Francis Allen still in ownership of the patent? Or did he sell it? If so, when?

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way to tell without asking him. The patent expired many years ago so doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any data sources one can check for the current owner of a patent. The best bet is either a web search, or an attempt to contact the original assignee of the patent. In this case, the patent expired many years ago so the current owner would seem to be a moot point.